# $V_2$ is complete implies set of all continuous bounded functions $f:V_1\to V_2$ complete

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

Let $(V_1, \lVert \cdot \rVert_{V_1})$ be a normed vector space and $(V_1, \lVert \cdot \rVert_{V_2})$ be a complete normed vector space. Let $C_b(V_1, V_2)$ be the set of all continuous bounded functions $f:V_1\to V_2$. Prove that $\left(C_b(V_1, V_2),\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty\right)$ is complete.

I'm a bit puzzled here. Let $\{x_n\}\subseteq V_1$ be a Cauchy sequence. Since $V_1$ is not necessarily complete, $\{x_n\}$ may not converge in $V_1$. Now let $\{f_m\}\subseteq C_b(V_1,V_2)$  be a sequence of functions. Then is it true that $f_m(\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} x_n)$ is generally undefined if $V_1$ is not complete?

Also, we know that if $f_m$ converges to some function $f$, then $\lim\limits_{m\to \infty} \lVert f_m - f_k \rVert = 0$ implies that $f_m$ converges uniformly. Thus $f \in C(V_1,V_2)$. All we need to prove in this case is that $f$ is also bounded. Is this correct?

> My approach to proof:

Let $\{f_m\}\subseteq C_b(V_1, V_2)$ be a Cauchy sequence of functions, then $f_m$ converges uniformly, which implies that $f_m(x)$ converges pointwise for all $x\in V_1$. So, $f_m(x)\subseteq V_2$. Let $S\subset V_1$ be a compact set and restrict $f_m$ to $f_m:S\to V_2$. Then, for all $x\in S$, $f_m$ maps $x$ to some $y\in K\subset V_2$, where $K$ is a compact set. Since $V_2$ is complete, $K$ is complete. Thus, for all $x\in S$, $f_m(x)$ converges to $f(x) \in K$, so $f(x)$ is bounded. Since $\{f_m\}$ converges uniformly, $f$ must be bounded, hence $f\in C_b(V_1, V_2)$.

Now I just realized that I have an error in my proof, since $f_m$ is bounded on $V_1$, regardless of whether or not $f_m$ maps compact sets to compact sets. So, what if we suppose that $f:V_1\to H\subset V_2$ and extend $H$ to $closure(H)$, so $closure(H)$ is compact? Then $closure(H)$ is complete, so $f_m$ must converge either in $H$ or on its boundary.

Please let me know if this is correct.

Comment: No, you **need** to show that a Cauchy sequence in $C_b$ has a limit in $C_b$. Hint: For each $x\in V_1$ the sequence $\{ f_m(x) \}$ is Cauchy in $V_2$ and thus has a limit in $V_2$. Thus, $f_m$ converges **pointwise** to a function $f$. You need to show that $f_m\to f$ uniformly. Then, $f$ is continuous and bounded (why?).

Comment: But if $C_b$ is equipped with $\lVert\cdot \rVert_\infty$, then doesn't this automatically mean that any Cauchy sequence $\{f_m\}$ in $C_b$ must converge w.r.t. this norm? But this implies that $\{f_m\}$ converges uniformly?

Comment: no. That is the definition of completeness, what you want to prove.

Comment: @user251257, does a Cauchy sequence necessarily converge in a normed vector space?

Comment: no. Again, that is what completeness for.

Comment: Say, if $\{f_m\}$ is Cauchy in $C_b$, but $C_b$ is not complete, then will $\{f_m\}$ converge to a point outside of $C_b$, but still converge?

Comment: $C_b$ is complete if $V_2$ is complete. What is "outside" $C_b$?

Comment: By definition, all Cauchy sequences in $V$ converge to a point in  $V$ under some norm if $V$ is normed and complete. Does this mean that if $V$ is normed but not complete then a Cauchy sequence will still converge, but not in $V$? What I mean is that the definition is not precise in saying whether or not a Cauchy sequence will necessarily converge (but not necessarily in the same vector space of which the sequence is a subset). So, is it possible to have $\{f_m\}\subset V$ converge to $f\subset U$, where $V$ and $U$ are normed vector spaces?

Comment: Consider $C[-1,1]$ with the $L_1$ norm. Then, the continuous piecewise linear function $f_n$ with $f_n(-1) = f_n(-1/n) = 0$ and $f_n(1/n) = f_n(1) = 1$ is Cauchy but has no limit in $C[-1,1]$.

Comment: a metric space need not be a subspace of a complete metric space. Every metric space does have a completion. However, that won't help you with your question.

Comment: So, in my question, if $\{f_m\}$ is Cauchy then it either diverges or it converges in $V_2$ (if we suppose that $V_2$ is not complete)? What if it does converge, but in the completion of $V_2$? I.e., we take the limit of $\{f_m\}$ in the sup-norm and see that convergence does happen, but the limit is simply not in $V_2$? I guess that's impossible :)

Comment: $\{ f_m(x) \}$ for some $x\in V_1$. There is a difference between a sequence of functions and a sequence of function values at some particular point $x$. The completion of a metric space is technically not a superset. You are focusing on stuff that are usually taught after the completeness of $C_b$ and it won't help you. If you are interested in that topic, you might want to lookup metric completion or ask a new question.

Comment: In order to build my proof, I need to be sure that a Cauchy sequence may diverge in $V$ if $V$ is not complete.

Comment: I gave you an example and again it is the definition of (non) completeness.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand the function definition in your example. So I don't see how to test if $f_n$ is convergent or not in C[-1,1].

Comment: another example: the subspace of polynomials is not closed in $C[0,1]$ with the supremum norm, thus it is not complete. Consider the power series to the exponential function.